# Android with Kotlin - pass data back to previous Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I want to pass data from Activity 2 back to Activity 1 but it doesnt work. I tried to solve with onActivityResult, but it is never called.

This is my Acitvity 1 - ProductsActivity

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        Log.v("onActivityResult", "onActivityResult")
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            // 2
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // 3
                Log.v("onActivityResult", "onActivityResult")
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is my second Acitvity - the DetailsProductAcitivity

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()
        Log.v("onActivityResult", "on back pressed")
        val intent = Intent(this, ProductsActivity::class.java)
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
    }
```

Comment: Where are you sending data in this example? You haven't set anything in the intent

Comment: `super.onBackPressed()` will finish the calling Activity, so I believe that's the reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not getting called because:

1. You are not setting the result
2. You look like are creating a new activity instead of finishing the current one (?)

In your first activity:

```
private fun launchNewActivity() {
    val requestCode = [yourCodeHere]
    val intent = Intent(this, ProductDetailsActivity::class.java)
    startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)
}
```

In your Second activity

```
private fun passProductAsResult(product: Product) {
    val data = Intent()
    data.putExtra("product", product.toString());

    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
    finish()
}
```

Back in your First Activity `override` the method `onActivityResult`

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
     if(resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return
     when(requestCode) {
         [yourRequestCode] -> { yourTextView.text = data.getStringExtra("product"); }
         // Other result codes
         else -> {}
     }
}
```

Make sure the data type is either `Serializable` or `Parcelable` if you're using complex data types.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. I think the startActivityForResult is important here. And the setResult() and finish()

Answer (score 2):

**Activity 1**

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
```

**Activity 2**

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()        
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.putExtra("Key",data)
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish()
}
```

**Activity 1 again**

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        Log.v("onActivityResult", "onActivityResult")
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                //get extra data from data intent here
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you know why the resultCode is 0 instead of RESULT_OK?

Answer (score 1):

In your Activity 2 you have to do like below

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        Log.v("onActivityResult", "on back pressed")
        val data = new Intent()
        data.putExtra(INTENT_PRODUCT_CHANGED, productChanged)
        //startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data)
        finish()    
    }
```

you have to just remove `super.onBackPressed()`

Answer (score 0):

You should use not

`startActivityForResult(intent, 1)`

but

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

Comment: Thanks. But you have to call startAcitivityForResult from the first Activity to start the second.

Answer (score 0):

I have another problem.

The onActivityResult will be called now but the data is null. And the resultCode is 0.

Activity 1:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
```

And this

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if(requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val resultString = data!!.getStringExtra(DetailsProductActivity.INTENT_PRODUCT_CHANGED)
        }
    }
}
```

Activity 2:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()
        Log.v("onActivityResult", "on back pressed")
        val data = Intent()
        data.putExtra(INTENT_PRODUCT_CHANGED, productChanged)
        //startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data)
        finish()    
    }
```

Comment: have you check my answer?